# Date not showing in citations natbib

Tags: latex, biblatex

I'm using `nat bib` for `beamer` and my citations are all showing up with `n.d.`, despite the citations having a date in the bib file.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{agsm}
\usepackage[german]{babel}

\begin{document}
  \begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Example citation}
    This is an example text with a citation from \citep{burzio1988ItalianSyntaxGovernmentBindingApproach} (← which is without date here and in the bibliography)
  \end{frame}

  \begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Bibliography}
    \bibliography{MyLibrary}
  \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Here's the citation information in the bib file (which is in the same working folder):

```
  @article{burzio1988ItalianSyntaxGovernmentBindingApproach,
  title = {Italian {{Syntax}}: {{A Government-Binding Approach}}},
  shorttitle = {Italian {{Syntax}}},
  author = {Burzio, Luigi},
  date = {1988-03},
  journaltitle = {Language},
  shortjournal = {Language},
  volume = {64},
  number = {1},
  eprint = {414791},
  eprinttype = {jstor},
  pages = {130},
  issn = {00978507},
  doi = {10.2307/414791}
}
```

This happens with all citations styles on natbib. I don't know what's happening. I'll appreciate the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For bibtex, use the old `year` and `month` fields instead of `date`:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{agsm}
\usepackage[german]{babel}

\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{\jobname.bib}
  @article{burzio1988ItalianSyntaxGovernmentBindingApproach,
  title = {Italian {{Syntax}}: {{A Government-Binding Approach}}},
  shorttitle = {Italian {{Syntax}}},
  author = {Burzio, Luigi},
  year = 1988,
  month = 3,
  journaltitle = {Language},
  shortjournal = {Language},
  volume = {64},
  number = {1},
  eprint = {414791},
  eprinttype = {jstor},
  pages = {130},
  issn = {00978507},
  doi = {10.2307/414791}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}
  \begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Example citation}
    This is an example text with a citation from \citep{burzio1988ItalianSyntaxGovernmentBindingApproach} (← which is without date here and in the bibliography)
  \end{frame}

  \begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Bibliography}
    \bibliography{\jobname}
  \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you prefer to use the `date` field, switch from bibtex to biblatex. Biblatex not only supports the superior `date` field, but is also much more flexible and easier to customise.

Comment: Thanks, it was the Biblatex solution that worked! Thanks a lot!